# How could i transfer duplicate items in other ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an array list

```
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
  list.add("Apple"); 
  list.add("Ball");  
  list.add("Ball");  
  list.add("Cat");  
  list.add("Cat");  
  list.add("dog");
```

and I want to transfer duplicate strings to other ArrayList.

I mean 2nd array list should only contain Ball and Cat not Apple and dog.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: will the array's duplicates always be next to each other in the list?
and is this second list alowed to have duplicates as well? e.i. if there are 3 cat instances, is the second list to have 1 cat or 2?

Comment: yes every duplicates next to each other ... and if there are 3 cat I only want a single cat to other arraylist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Custom list to ensure that one duplicate gets added to a list at most as
// opposed to n-1 instances (only two instances of a value in this list would 
// be deceiving).
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Apple");
list.add("Ball");
list.add("Ball");
list.add("Ball");
list.add("Ball");
list.add("Cat");
list.add("Cat");
list.add("Cat");
list.add("dog");
list.add("dog");

Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> setOfDuplicates = new HashSet<>();
for (String s : list) {
    if (!set.add(s)) { // Remember that sets do not accept duplicates
        setOfDuplicates.add(s);
    }
}

List<String> listOfDuplicates = new ArrayList<>(setOfDuplicates);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `listOfDuplicates` contain `n-1` instances if the original list contains `n` instances of a given string?

Comment: @BhalchandraSW Good catch. Edited!

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
List<String> duplicates = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String str: list) {
   if(Collections.frequency(list, str) > 1) {
       duplicates.add(str);
   }
}
```

`duplicates` will contain your duplicates

Comment: Your code is working fine but I only want one cat not both cat in the new array.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `Set` as a way to help determine the duplicated elements then simply return an `ArrayList` of those elements.

```
public static ArrayList<String> retainDuplicates(ArrayList<String> inputList){
       Set<String> tempSet = new HashSet<>();
       ArrayList<String> duplicateList =  new ArrayList<>();
       for (String elem : inputList) {
            if(!tempSet.add(elem)) duplicateList.add(elem);
       }
       return duplicateList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```

call the method like so:

```
ArrayList<String> resultList = retainDuplicates(list);
```

note that I've used `distinct()` to remove any elements that occur more than once within the `duplicateList`. However, if you want to keep the duplicates regardless of theirs occurrences within the `duplicateList` then just perform `return duplicateList;` rather than `return duplicateList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));`.

Comment: Let me try... :)

Comment: thanks for the help but I don't want to use min API level 24.

Comment: @PankazKumar then just do `return duplicateList;` as mentioned within my answer.

Answer (score 2):

since you said your duplicates will all be next to each other, you can itterate through the list in pairs, and if the pair's elements match, there is a duplicate

here would be the general pseudo code for it

```
int first = 0
int second = 1
for (arraySize)
    if (array[first] == array[second])
       //there is a match here
       newArray.add(array[first])
    first += 1
    second += 1
```

Note that this does not check the bounds of the array, which should be easy to implement yourself

now as for the second list not having duplicate items, you can simply store a variable with the last transfered item, and if the new found duplicate is the same, dont transfer it again

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
  list.add("Apple"); 
  list.add("Ball");  
  list.add("Ball");  
  list.add("Cat");  
  list.add("Cat");  
  list.add("dog");

List<String> duplicateList= new ArrayList<String>();
for(String str: list) {
   if(Collections.frequency(list, str) > 1) {
       duplicateList.add(str);
   }
}

System.out.println(duplicateList.toString());
//Here you will get duplicate String from the original list.
```